# How to bind a complex object to an ActionFilterAttribute ActionParameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

My question is fairly simple: I have a custom ActionFilterAttribute which looks like this (simplified for readability):

```
public class DynamicModuleActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        filterContext.ActionParameters["module"] = new MyObject();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then, my controller action should look like this:

```
[DynamicModuleAction]
public ActionResult Edit(Module module) {
    // do some logic here
    return View();
}
```

With this code, I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` in the `DefaultModelBinder`.
Of course I could receive an `object` module in the action and then cast it to `Module`, but, obviously, I'm trying to avoid this workaround.
Any clues?
Thanks everyone!